# Yii2 kartik file input issue , Browse button submitting the form

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

I have created a form with yii2 kartik fileinput widget.But there is an issue in it.I cant browse the images.Browse button submitting the form.

Here is my fileinput widget

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'file[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'showPreview'=>false,
        'showCaption' => false,
        'showRemove' => false,
        'showUpload' => false,
        'showCancel' => false,
        'browseClass' => 'btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-block',
        'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
        'browseLabel' =>  'Select Photo'
    ],
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*']
]);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not a problem with the widget but there may be a problem with your form. Given that you only include the widget code in your question, it is not possible to make a definitive comment.

Another point is that when you want to get multiple files in your field, you need to add `'multiple' => true` in the `options` section.

So, code will be as follows:

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'file[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => [
        'accept' => 'image/*',
        'multiple' => true
    ]
]);?>
```